# if else statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm having a problem with this question can anyone help? an explanation would be nice rather than the answer the answer it self.

Write a statement that compares the values of  score1 and  score2 and takes the following actions. When  score1 exceeds  score2 , the message "player1 wins" is printed to standard out. When  score2 exceeds  score1 , the message "player2 wins" is printed to standard out. In each case, the variables  player1Wins, ,  player1Losses ,  player2Wins, and  player2Losses, , are incremented when appropriate. Finally, in the event of a tie, the message "tie" is printed and the variable  tieCount is incremented.

```
    if(score1>score2)
     {
         System.out.println("player1 wins");
         player1Wins++;player2Losses++;
     }
    else if(score2>score1)
     {
         System.out.println("player2 wins");
         player2Wins++;player1Losses++;
     }
    else if(score1=score2)
     {
        System.out.println("tie");
        tieCount++;
     }
```

Comment: What is the actual question? You've described what the code is meant to do, and shown us some code, but not what is wrong with it? Also - I would have a second-look at the if statement for the tie. It doesn't look right to me.

Comment: There is a typo/wrong operator used in the condition for the tie case, it should be `score1 == score2`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything is fine **except** the last **else if**. Where you accidentely did an assignment rather than comparison.

```
else if(score1=score2)
```

The above *else-if* statement should be: -

```
else if(score1 == score2)
```

---

***P.S***: -
In fact, you can remove the *last* `else if` with just simple `else` That will be equivalent to this else if. Since you have already considered your other possibility in your first two condition.

So, this will also do it: -

```
else {
    System.out.println("tie");
    tieCount++;

}
```

Comment: IT shouldn't even be an else-if statement. A simple else would suffice

Answer (score 3):

An *assignment* is being performed in the last `else if` condition, not an *comparison*. Change to:

```
else if (score1 == score2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with equality which may be causing a problem

```
else if(score1=score2) {
    System.out.println("tie");
    tieCount++;
}
```

should be

```
else if(score1==score2) {
    System.out.println("tie");
    tieCount++;
}
```

Your first one will assign the value of score2 to score1. It is the last else though so will probably be called even with this bug as the other two check for greater than and less than.

Apart from that your code seems to do what it should.

Answer (score 1):

`else if(score1 == score2)` should be done. The `=` operator means assignment, whereas `==` means check for equality.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the last condition being syntactically wrong, it is also redundant. Replace the final `else if ...` with just `else` and everything will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(score1=score2)
```

This statement should be

```
else if(score1 == score2)
```

but this compares the references actually it should be

```
else if(score1.equals(score2))
```

Comment: What if the scores is a primitive int? And even if you consider them reference, then you need to point out the problem with first 2 comparison also.

Answer (score 0):

I think last statement has probem you are using = sign istead of == sign use

```
if(score1==score2)
```